# how to set frangmenttabhost Tabs at the middle of the screen

Tags: java, android, android-source

I am trying to create an app in which i want to set the Frangmenttabhost Tabs in the middle of the screen.
I have so far made it on the bottom but cant move to the middle.
Would be appreciating a help.
Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```